# Hide a 2nd Monitor from a Programs Print Screen

Tags: print-screen

I run 2 monitors on a PC that also runs a program for the Freelancing site Elance.com.  The program they provide, takes screenshots and uploads them to my account for a client to see at different intervals.

My goal is to make the screenshot that the program takes and uploads, to somehow only take a shot of my "Main" or "Defualt" monitor and ignore my 2nd monitor.  The main reason is my 2nd monitor generally has private data that I do not displayed to the world on a website.

Does anyone know if there is any kind of program or trick I can use that will make it appear that I have 1 monitor when a Screenshot is taken?  I am not sure how the program does it and how that works as I am a web developer and not a C++ or any kind of low level programmer.  If the Elance program simply runs the same function that is called when a PrintScreen key is pressed on a keyboard, then I am thinking it might be possible to maybe trick that into only the default desktop?

Any ideas or help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: eLance (and a regular PrintScreen) are taking a shot of your "Desktop", and your desktop spans all monitors.  Regardless, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 3):

You could install the screenshot software (along with whatever you need to take screenshots of) inside a virtual machine, using a free program like [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or VMWare Player.

You could then run your other applications normally, outside of the virtual machine, and the screenshot software would not be able to access them. This works great with a multi-monitor setup like the one you describe, since you can have the virtualized OS on one monitor and your regular OS on the other.

Comment: Good idea, I have Virtualbox, I just don't use it much.  I give this a try though, thank you.  I will select this as answer if nothing better comes up soon

Comment: If you are writing your code(or anything that the client will pay for) outside of virtual machine, then that useful work will not be accessible by the elance tracker. So you will have to do all that work that is to be paid inside virtualbox only.